# Correct and elegant set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose the set A = $\{ j_1, j_2, j_3\}$. Let's say that the elements of the set can assume positive integer values. For instance, 
$j_1=1, j_2=1, j_3=3\\j_1=2, j_2=3, j_3=3, \\...$

How can I write a set-builder notation so that the objects $j_k$ assumes the same value? For Instance:

$$B = \{j_1, j_2\}\subset A \text { because } j_1 = j_2 = 1 \text{ and } C = \{ j_3 \} \text{ because } j_3=3 \text{ only. }$$

or

$B = \{j_1\}\subset A \text{ because } j_1 = 2$ only and $C = \{ j_2, j_3 \}$ because $j_2=j_3=3$.

I would like to avoid written expressions such that,
$B = \{ j_k \mid j_k \mbox{ are the elements with same attributed value.} \}$

Comment: There's no point in doing this because at most one element can have an attributed value.  The set $\{1,1,2\}$ is not an acceptable set.  Now can do things like $\{p_k|k\ge 2$ where $p_k$ is the smallest prime divisor of $k\}$ so $p_2=2$ and $p_5=5$ and $p_6=3$ and we might notice that $p_2=2$ and $p_4=2$ so even the we list the set $\{p_k\}= \{p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,....\}$ the actual elements do *not* repeat and the $p_2$ and $p_4$ are *not* two elements. The are *one* element listed twice.  The set actually is $\{2,3,5,7,11...\}=\{$primes$\}$ but just inefficiently written.

Answer (score 1):

A = { x : x in A } is the simplest set builder notation describing A as the set of its elements.

Sets do not have multiples of the same element.
{a,a} = {a} for example.
If you want multiples of the same elements then use n-tuplets, bags or multisets.

The set A with values of natural numbers
is described by A subset N.

Frequently the use of subscripts is unnecessary and clumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Sets can not have multiple elements of the same value.

If $j_1 = 1, j_2 = 1, j_3=3$ then then set $\{j_1,j_2,j_3\} = \{1,3\}$ and $|\{j_1, j_2, j_3\}| = 2$.  This because $j_1=j_2$ and the set only has two elements.

Now when we write a set $\{j_1, j_2, j_3\}$ the assumption is that $j_1,j_2, j_3$ are distinct.  And if we know they are not we *should* not right the set as such.

But *occasionally* it is unavoidable in cases where we don't know the values of our notations.  For example if $A \subset \mathbb N$ and we writhe $f(A) = \{f(a)|a\in A\}$ we have no way of knowing when $a,b \in A$ but $a\ne b$ whether or not $f(a) = f(b)$ or not.  If $f(a)=f(b)$ then it would appear the description of $f(A) = \{f(a)|a\in A\}$ is ineffective and that value $f(a)$ was described twice, once as $f(a)$ and once as $f(b)$.  Oh, well.. it couldn't have been avoided.  But it's *vital* to realize the $f(a) \in f(A)$ and $f(b)\in f(A)$ are *not* two different elements.  They are *one* element.

Indeed if $f(n) = 7$ then the set $f(\mathbb N)= \{f(n)|n\in \mathbb N\} = \{f(1),f(2),f(3), f(4)..... \} = \{7\}$.  It is a set with *ONE* only $1$ element in it.

So for you case $j_1 = j_2=1$ and $j_3=3$ then your set builder notation is $\{j_1\}$ and $\{j_3\}$.

And if you say $B = \{ j_k \mid j_k \mbox{ are the elements with same attributed value.} \}$

Then $B = \{j_k\}$ that's it.  It doesn't matter if $j_m, j_l, j_i$ all are the same value.  That means $j_m=j_l=j_i$ and your set has *one* element.  It doesn't matter which notation you use; it is a set with *ONE* element.